# useLayoutEffect should only be used in components that render exclusively on the client

Tags: reactjs, next.js, usehooks-ts

I got this warning:

```
Warning: useLayoutEffect does nothing on the server, because its effect cannot be encoded into the server renderer's output format. This will lead to a mismatch between the initial, non-hydrated UI and the intended UI. To avoid this, useLayoutEffect should only be used in components that render exclusively on the client. See https://reactjs.org/link/uselayouteffect-ssr for common fixes.
    at Layout (webpack-internal:///./tikexModule/pages/hu/dashboard/organizations/[organizationId]/layouts/[layoutId]/index.tsx:82:103)
    at main
```

But in this page, or for this componenet no server side rendering is applied. There is no `getStaticPath`, `getStaticProps`, or `getServerSideProps` applied. Then why error raised?

Using https://usehooks-ts.com library.

One of the subcomponent uses `useEventListener.ts`  and it imports:

```
import useIsomorphicLayoutEffect from './useIsomorphicLayoutEffect'
```

this code:

```js
function useEventListener<
    KW extends keyof WindowEventMap,
    KH extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap,
    T extends HTMLElement | void = void
>(
    eventName: KW | KH,
    handler: (
        event: WindowEventMap[KW] | HTMLElementEventMap[KH] | Event
    ) => void,
    element?: RefObject<T>
) {
    // Create a ref that stores handler
    const savedHandler = useRef(handler)

    useIsomorphicLayoutEffect(() => {
        savedHandler.current = handler
    }, [handler])
```

So yes, `useIsomorphicLayoutEffect` is used.

What is the fundamental issue here, if no SSR is used?

I tried to put these critical logic inside and check is it client side:

```
const Canvas = ({
    seatPriceDifferences,
    layout,
    sectors,
    selectedRowIndex,
    onSelectRowOnCanvas,
    onUnselect,
    backgroundImageURL,
    pointerPosition,
    onPointerPositionChange,
}: Props) => {
    const maxX = 1000
    const maxY = 1000 / (layout?.aspectRatio ?? 1)

    let pt = undefined
    let canvasSVG = undefined
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        canvasSVG = useRef(null)
        useEventListener('pointermove', handlePointerPositionChange)
        useEventListener('pointerdown', handlePointerPositionChange)
        pt = canvasSVG?.current?.createSVGPoint() ?? { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }

    function handlePointerPositionChange(evt) {
        pt.x = evt?.clientX ?? 0
        pt.y = evt?.clientY ?? 0
```

Comment: No SSR is when you dynamically render a component with `ssr: false`. https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr. Everything else is SSR. Does not matter if `getXXX` methods are used or not.

Comment: _"But in this page, or for this componenet no server side rendering is applied"_ - By default, [Next.js pre-renders every page on the server](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#pre-rendering) unless you explicitly tell it not to. It doesn't matter if you're using data fetching methods or not.